# React: Can i call a function component from a Class component on demand?

Tags: reactjs, function, class

I made a function component which calculates and returns page buttons based on API values, and i need to call that function whenever i click a button in order for it to update. The onClick() function is inside the Class component, and i need to call the function component from withing that onClick() function. And i'm having trouble making it work:

function:

```
    function Paging(props) {
      const apiPaging = props.state.apiPaging
      const renderPageNumbers = apiPaging.map((links, index) => {
        return <button key={index} id={index} 
                url={links.url}
                onClick={props.data.handleClick} 
                className={links.active ? "mark-page" : "" } 
                >{links.label}
                </button>     
    })
    return (
           <div id = "page-nums">
                {renderPageNumbers}
           </div>
          )
```

class:

```
     handleClick(event) {

        this.fetchApi()
        > Need it here <

    }

    return(
         <div>
               <Paging 
                data = {this}
                state = {this.state}
                />
          </div>
        )
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear if you are wanting to call a function of the child component from the parent, or if you are passing a callback from the parent to the child to attach to the button rendered in the child. You can't call React functions though, if ***that*** is your question. Maybe I am just missing what you are asking for, but from what I can tell, what you are saying you want is to be able to call from the parent is stuff the parent already has and passed as props to a child component.

Comment: @DrewReese the Paging() function is a seperate component, it is imported through the Class one (which is like the main component), and inside that Class one, there is an onClick function. It's a bit convoluted, i know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass `handleClick` to `Paging`component:

```
<Paging handleClick={handleClick} state={this.state} />
```

And in `Paging`:

```
onClick={props.handleClick}
```

Comment: thank you, the buttons work, however i need to rerun the whole function (in order to get a different array of numbers) whenever i press that button, and it still does nothing.

Comment: I thing you should ask other question with description detail

Comment: actually nevermind, that did the trick. a also had to fix some value i was passing into a button and now it works as it should, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
<Paging handleClick={handleClick} state={this.state} />
```

and in `Paging` :

```
onClick={(index)=>props.handleClick(index)}
```

in your `handleClick` function :

```
 handleClick(index) {
    this.fetchApi()
   // you have access to btn index here whith index variable
    > Need it here <

}
```